# create a dropdown list with check boxes inside it

Tags: c#, javascript, html, checkbox, dropdownbox

How to create a drop down list with check boxes inside it using plain Html and javascript? If not possible, can there be a chance to meet this requirement using c#.net? Kindly, help me.

Comment: As Im a newbie, code snippets would be of great help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://lab.arc90.com/2007/07/02/multiselect). It turns multiple select into a dropdown list with checkboxes

Comment: Your example exactly suits my requirements but unable to understand the source code of it properly. can you give a simplified small example of it pls?

Comment: You just need to include the js file. And after that you need to write `a$.WhenToUse = 'class'; ` where `class` is the class that you apply to multiple select that you need to behave as if they are with checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7c4/9/)?

or could always use a  jQuery/javascript plugin like [this](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own DropDownList.

- C#.Net approach : [This](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/3962.aspx) is exactly what you need. I won't copy the code since it is clearly explained in the link.
- HTML / JS Approach :

  ```
   <html> 
    <head> 
      <title>Scrolling Checkboxes</title> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      </script> 
     </head> 
    <body> 
     <div id="ScrollCB" style="height:150;width:200px;overflow:auto"> 
      <Label><input type="checkbox" id="scb1" name="scb1" value="1" />First Item</Label><br /> 
      <Label><input type="checkbox" id="scb2" name="scb2" value="2" />Second Item</Label><br /> 
      <Label><input type="checkbox" id="scb3" name="scb3" value="3" />Third Item</Label><br /> 
      ...
     </div> 
    </body> 
   </html>
  ```

You can try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/aUQdW/

Comment: `input` types and `line breaks(br)` are both stand alone tags and should be closed like `<br\>`. Also associating labels with checkboxes would be great, since clicking on the label would select/de-select the associated checlbox

Comment: I cannot see checkboxes like present in Dropdown list. Is any modification needed to this code?

Answer (score 0):

For  Dropdown list with checkbox in C sharp you have to use CheckedListBox of Windows Conntrol.Using some Properties ,you can get what you want .You can set Checked-Unchecked for item in list .

Comment: I'm using MVC3 architecture. I need the checkboxlist in the view. Could you pls put some codesnippet of that checkboxlist?